# Name for a directed acyclic graph with no skip-level edges?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology, directed-graphs

I'm looking at a specific class of DAGs, namely those DAGs such that any path from $u$ to $v$ has the same length. Informally, we don't allow "skip-level" edges. I understand these graphs are the DAGs that are their own transitive reduction.

I added a small number of examples below.

Thank you!

[image: A few example graphs]

Comment: I have seen these called "layered digraphs" but I don't know how common that is.

Comment: (+1) "Layered" is definitely the commonly-used term here.